# Jquery json add new row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

hello i want to make a html table and populate rows live through json and add only new info from database through php/mysql like so:

php code:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from generalTabl");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo '{"Info1":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

jquery code:

```
function getData(){
    var url = "/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(jsonData) {
        $.each(jsonData.Info1, function(nr,jsonData){
            $("#tt").append('<tr>' +jsonData.titlu+'</tr>')
        })
    })
}
setInterval("getData()" ,1000);
```

and how make to populate only last with only new information from database

and problem is every time setInterval fireup the function add new row  instead of adding row only if info is new

Comment: Hi, what is the question? (maybe you are not yet finished editing it)

Comment: It's going to be difficult for us to help you if we don't know what the code is doing that it's not supposed to (or not doing that it is supposed to).

Comment: it seems to me you should be using data2 inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, a few notes on your existing code.

First of all, your use of the `Info1` key is completely redundant. Change your last line of PHP to this:

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then in your jQuery change your `$.each` line to this:

```
$.each(jsonData,function() {
```

Note that I've removed the arguments to the function since you don't appear to be using them.

Next, within your loop you are repeatedly calling on the *original object*'s `titlu` property which is probably not what you're after. Replace the loop's content with this:

```
$("#tt").append("<tr>"+this.titlu+"</tr>");
```

And finally you should ***never*** pass a string to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. In this case it's especially bad because all you need to do is use `setInterval(getData,1000);`.

---

With that out of the way, I would suggest making sure each row has an ID. Then, when appending to your table, try something like this:

```
if(!document.getElementById("row"+this.id))
    $("#tt").append("<tr id='row"+this.id+"'>"+this.titlu+"</tr>");
```

Comment: i know but problem is the add rows with old info instead of adding only row if in data base is new info.

Comment: If you implement the code I gave at the end, it will only add new data.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, use `data2` instead of `jsonData`

```
$.each(jsonData.Info1, function(nr,data2){
    $("#tt").append('<tr>' +data2.titlu+'</tr>')
})
```

Assuming the JSON data you are getting from server has a property called `Info1` and it has a collection with a property called `titlu` in that.

To append only the new items, You may check the record id ( possibly the unique- primary key of the from the table) to see whether that already exists in the list/table. If not,append.

Comment: Does not answer the question. "how make to populate only last with ***only new information*** from database"

Comment: @Kolink: Answered before he added that part of question. I thought he is struggling to see the newly appended items in the view.